# How can I Install The Python T-Matrix Library in Google Colab?

Tags: matrix, installation, pip, module

I'm having issues with installing and importing the python t-matrix module on
google Collaboratory.

Here is what I tried in the image below:

`!pip install pytmatrix`

[image]

I Got an error No module named 'pytmatrix' after importing:
`import pytmatix`

[image]